# GDI+ returns either real size or 0 of an image file

Tags: c++, image, winapi, gdi+

I am trying to read images sizes. When I specify images by file path all works OK, but when I use winapi to get the very same file paths via searching for all files in a folder, I get 0 sizes. Here is the sample code.

```
    
    
    #include <list>
    #include <memory>
    #include <string>
    #include <windows.h>
    
    #include <gdiplus.h>
    #pragma comment(lib, "Gdiplus.lib")
    
    class GDIPlus final
    {
    public:
        GDIPlus()
        {
            Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&mGDIPlusToken, &mGDIPlusStartupInput, NULL);
        }
    
        ~GDIPlus()
        {
            Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(mGDIPlusToken);
        }
    
    private:
        Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput    mGDIPlusStartupInput;
        ULONG_PTR                       mGDIPlusToken;
    } gdiPlus;
    
    using Image = Gdiplus::Image;
    using ImagePtr = std::unique_ptr<Image>;
    
    int main()
    {
    #if 0 // Success
        std::list<std::wstring> fileNames{
            L"C:\\Test\\Untitled.gif",
            L"C:\\Test\\AlphaJPG.jpg",
        };
    #else // Failure
        std::list<std::wstring> fileNames;
        WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
        HANDLE hFind = ::FindFirstFile(L"C:\\Test\\*", &data);
    
        if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFind)
        {
            static const auto   skipAttributes{ FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY };
            do
            {
                if (data.dwFileAttributes & skipAttributes)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                fileNames.push_back(data.cFileName);
            } while (::FindNextFile(hFind, &data));
    
            ::FindClose(hFind);
        }
    #endif
    
        for (const auto& fileName : fileNames)
        {
            ImagePtr pImage{ Image::FromFile(fileName.c_str()) };
            if (pImage.get())
            {
                ::wprintf(L"%s width = %d height = %d\n", fileName.c_str(), pImage->GetWidth(), pImage->GetHeight());
            };
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

The result is the same no matter how many files I am reading.

PS: It's just a test, for in the bigger project I got the same zero-sizes issue and, unfortunately, I cannot specify file paths explicitly.

Comment: *"the very same file paths"* - You aren't. You are using a *substantially* different way to access file system objects. While you are using fully qualified path names in the case where everything works (which you should be using, **always**), you are using relative path names in the error case. That's what you need to fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't notice the folder part was missing...